# Пропали иконки ассоциации файлов с MS Office. Как вернуть?

Tags: windows, office

В общем, все файлы, которые должны открываться через MS Office имеют иконки, как будто с ними не сопоставлена программа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если файлы открыть, то они успешно автоматически открываются через нужное Office-приложение.

В свойствах тоже ассоциация есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать восстановление Office 2016, но не помогло.

```
sfc /scannow тоже не помог.
```

Так же пробовал удалять кеш-иконок из AppData, но опять же без толку .

Показывание расширения файлов включено и там нету в конце чего-то подобного `.xlsx.exe` => это не вирусня.

В системном трее, запущенная программа так же отображается без иконки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Под другим пользователем так же всё плохо?

Comment: А тупо Открыть с помощью - Другая программа - Найти - Word/Excel - Открывать всегда ?

Comment: @Akina, там стоят нужные программы. Т.е ассоциация есть, но иконок нету...

Comment: Вы всё-таки попробуйте, как будто ассоциации нет...

Comment: @Akina, outlook например, тоже отображается в системном трее как-будто у него нету иконки.

Comment: Давайте не путать икону приложения и икону ассоциированного файла.. ушли и те, и эти? тогда проверьте, не случилось ли чего нехорошего с правами доступа к каталогу с исполняемыми файлами.

Comment: @Akina, дополнил вопрос тем, как я вижу это все.

Comment: После очистки кэша иконок imageres.dll  восстанавливали тоже?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, с imageres.dll ничего не делал.

Comment: Сейчас опишу способ, который мне помогал не раз на Windows 7 через очистку кэша и замену imageres.dll

Answer (score 1):

Как я решал пару раз подобные проблемы (у меня, правда, слетали иконки не офиса, а нескольких био-утилит):

1. Ищем файл imageres.dll в подпапках Windows, у меня находится модифицированный в папке c:\windows\system32 и оригинальный в папке C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-imageres_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_38b294da11970cde
2. Создаем CMD-файл (приведен в конце сообщения), меняя, где необходимо, пути на свои
3. Запускаем командную строку под админом (я пользую FAR)
4. Выходим из проводника (Пуск, Ctrl+Shift и правый клик на свободном месте)
5. Выполняем наш CMD-файл в командной строке и затем же из неё запускаем проводник (explorer.exe)

Всё нормально восстанавливалось (работало в Vista, Win7 и Win8)

Текст CMD-файла:

```
del "C:\Users\ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.db"
del  C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll
copy "C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-imageres_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_38b294da11970cde\imageres.dll" "C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll"
```

Comment: А у меня в этих 2-ух местах эти файлы имеют одинаковую дату последней модификации 2009 год и вес идентичный.

Comment: @iluxa1810 на том компьютере, с которого я сейчас пишу, у меня то же самое.

Comment: Т.е заменять не имеет смысла?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Не факт. Сейчас попробовал сделать это, иконки после перезапуска помигали.

Comment: Хм... Что-то у меня прав нету на удаление этого файла.

Comment: @iluxa1810 под админом? Может, отсюда и ноги растут? Получите права.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это из-за того, что на днях я грохнул папку C:\Windows\Installer  =( В интернете нашел похожие симптомы после этого.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Хм, по идее, не должно приводить именно к такой ошибке (к другим - сколько угодно, но не к этой).